# VTC of Pass Transistor AND gate in LTSPICE

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, logic-gates, cmos

I am trying to plot the voltage transfer characteristic of this pass-transistor AND gate in Ltspice

[image]

in order to obtain the following graph:

[image]

However, when I tried to do it, I did not obtain the correct output:

[image]

[image]

I tried to choose a value for C, but I am not sure if it is correct. I have tried so many things to get this circuit to work but cannot get the correct output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the Berkeley Model.

---

*PROCESS :  0.25um EE141          (2.5V)
*SPICE MODEL     BSIM3 - V3.1

***************** CORNER_LIB OF TYPICAL MODEL *******************

.LIB TT
.param toxp = 5.8e-9 toxn = 5.8e-9 
+dxl = 0 dxw = 0 
+dvthn = 0 dvthp = 0 
+cjn = 2.024128E-3    cjp = 1.931092e-3
+cjswn = 2.751528E-10  cjswp = 2.232277e-10
+cgon =  3.11E-10 cgop = 2.68e-10
+cjgaten = 2.135064E-10 cjgatep = 1.607088e-10
+hdifn = 3.1e-07 hdifp = 3.1e-7 
.lib 'berkeley_model.txt' MOS
.ENDL TT

*************CORNER_LIB OF  SNSP   MODEL ***********

.LIB SS
.param toxp = 6.1e-9 toxn = 6.1e-9 
+dxl = 2.5e-8 dxw = -3e-8 
+dvthn = 0.06 dvthp = -0.06
+cjn = 2.2265408E-3 cjp = 2.1242e-3
+cjswn = 3.0266808E-10 cjswp = 2.4555e-10 
+cgon = 3.421E-10 cgop = 2.948e-10 
+cjgaten = 2.3485704E-10 cjgatep = 1.7678e-10
+hdifn = 3.1e-07 hdifp = 3.1e-7
.lib 'berkeley_model.txt' MOS
.ENDL SS
**************** CORNER_LIB OF  FNFP   MODEL ***************************

.LIB FF
.param toxp = 5.5e-9 toxn = 5.5e-9 
+dxl = -2.5e-8 dxw = 3e-8
+dvthn = -0.06 dvthp = 0.06 
+cjn = 1.8217152e-3 cjp = 1.738e-3
+cjswn = 2.4763752e-10 cjswp = 2.009e-10 
+cgon = 2.799e-10 cgop = 2.412e-10 
+cjgaten = 1.9215576e-10 cjgatep = 1.4464e-10
+hdifn = 3.1e-07 hdifp = 3.1e-7 
.lib 'berkeley_model.txt' MOS
.ENDL FF
**************** CORNER_LIB OF  SNFP   MODEL ****************************

.LIB SF
.param toxp = 5.8e-9 toxn = 5.8e-9 
+dxl = 0 dxw = 0
+dvthn = 0.06 dvthp = 0.06
+cjn = 2.2265408E-3 cjp = 1.738e-3
+cjswn = 3.0266808E-10 cjswp = 2.009e-10 
+cgon =  3.11E-10 cgop = 2.68e-10
+cjgaten = 2.3485704E-10 cjgatep = 1.4464e-10
+hdifp = 3.1e-7 hdifn = 3.1e-07
.lib 'berkeley_model.txt' MOS
.ENDL SF
**************** CORNER_LIB OF  FNSP   MODEL ****************************

.LIB FS
.param toxp = 5.8e-9 toxn = 5.8e-9 
+dxl = 0 dxw = 0
+dvthn = -0.06 dvthp = -0.06
+cjn = 1.8217152e-3 cjp = 2.1242e-3
+cjswn = 2.4763752e-10 cjswp = 2.4555e-10 
+cgon =  3.11E-10 cgop = 2.68e-10 
+cjgaten = 1.9215576e-10 cjgatep = 1.7678e-10
+hdifp = 3.1e-7 hdifn = 3.1e-07
.lib 'berkeley_model.txt' MOS
.ENDL FS
*
.LIB MOS

*NMOS DEVICES MODEL

.MODEL nmos          NMOS   (
+LMIN    = 2.4E-07        LMAX    = '5.1E-07-dxl'
+LEVEL   = 49             TNOM    = 25             XL      = '3E-8 + dxl'
+XW      = '0 + dxw'      VERSION = 3.1            TOX     = toxn
+CALCACM = 1              SFVTFLAG= 0              VFBFLAG = 1
+XJ      = 1E-07          NCH     = 2.354946E+17   LLN     = 1
+LWN     = 1              WLN     = 1              WWN     = 1
+LINT    = 1.76E-08       WINT    = 6.75E-09       MOBMOD  = 1
+BINUNIT = 2              DWG     = 0              DWB     = 0
+VTH0    = '0.4321336+dvthn' LVTH0   = 2.081814E-08   WVTH0   = -5.470342E-11
+PVTH0   = -6.721795E-16  K1      = 0.3281252      LK1     = 9.238362E-08
+WK1     = 2.878255E-08   PK1     = -2.426481E-14  K2      = 0.0402824
+LK2     = -3.208392E-08  WK2     = -1.154091E-08  PK2     = 9.192045E-15
+K3      = 0              DVT0    = 0              DVT1    = 0
+DVT2    = 0              DVT0W   = 0              DVT1W   = 0
+DVT2W   = 0              NLX     = 0              W0      = 0
+K3B     = 0              VSAT    = 7.586954E+04   LVSAT   = 3.094656E-03
+WVSAT   = -1.747416E-03  PVSAT   = 8.820956E-10   UA      = 8.924498E-10
+LUA     = -1.511745E-16  WUA     = -3.509821E-17  PUA     = -3.08778E-23
+UB      = 8.928832E-21   LUB     = -1.655745E-27  WUB     = -2.03282E-27
+PUB     = 3.4578E-34     UC      = -1.364265E-11  LUC     = 1.170473E-17
+WUC     = -1.256705E-18  PUC     = -6.249644E-24  RDSW    = 447.8871
+PRWB    = 0              PRWG    = 0              WR      = 0.99
+U0      = 0.06005258     LU0     = -6.31976E-09   WU0     = -8.819531E-09
+PU0     = 3.57209E-15    A0      = -1.468837      LA0     = 6.419548E-07
+WA0     = 5.512414E-07   PA0     = -9.222928E-14  KETA    = -0.04922795
+LKETA   = 2.360844E-08   WKETA   = 1.560385E-08   PKETA   = -5.98377E-15
+A1      = 0.02659908     LA1     = -6.511454E-09  A2      = 1
+AGS     = -4.01637       LAGS    = 1.090294E-06   WAGS    = 1.162021E-06
+PAGS    = -3.108579E-13  B0      = 0              B1      = 0
+VOFF    = -0.1829426     LVOFF   = 9.941631E-09   WVOFF   = 1.568082E-08
+PVOFF   = -2.832958E-15  NFACTOR = 0.6790636      LNFACTOR= 3.454948E-08
+WNFACTOR= 1.501016E-07   PNFACTOR= -2.955591E-14  CIT     = 2.218499E-04
+LCIT    = -1.076934E-10  WCIT    = -3.286884E-10  PCIT    = 1.658928E-16
+CDSC    = 0              CDSCB   = 0              CDSCD   = 0
+ETA0    = 1.215578E-04   LETA0   = -1.037758E-11  WETA0   = -3.030225E-11
+PETA0   = 1.529658E-17   ETAB    = 3.548681E-03   LETAB   = -1.791374E-09
+WETAB   = -6.897268E-10  PETAB   = 3.481742E-16   DSUB    = 0
+PCLM    = 3.583838       LPCLM   = -6.874146E-07  WPCLM   = 5.664574E-08
+PPCLM   = -1.33176E-15   PDIBLC1 = 0              PDIBLC2 = 5.379674E-03
+LPDIBLC2= 7.808481E-09   WPDIBLC2= 5.516945E-10   PPDIBLC2= -2.784957E-16
+PDIBLCB = -0.1229374     LPDIBLCB= 4.956215E-08   WPDIBLCB= 3.299946E-08
+PPDIBLCB= -9.624918E-15  DROUT   = 0              PSCBE1  = 4.472639E+08
+LPSCBE1 = 28.64041       WPSCBE1 = 15.7154        PPSCBE1 = -7.933138E-06
+PSCBE2  = 1.842585E-06   LPSCBE2 = 2.871008E-12   WPSCBE2 = 2.579183E-12
+PPSCBE2 = -1.301972E-18  PVAG    = -2.015254E-03  LPVAG   = 1.017757E-09
+WPVAG   = 3.07622E-10    PPVAG   = -1.55418E-16   DELTA   = -0.02862256
+LDELTA  = 1.492454E-08   WDELTA  = -6.71663E-09   PDELTA  = 3.407521E-15
+ALPHA0  = 0              BETA0   = 30             KT1     = -0.2579945
+LKT1    = -1.664895E-08  WKT1    = -1.633463E-08  PKT1    = 3.755864E-15
+KT2     = -0.05347481    LKT2    = 8.244731E-09   WKT2    = 1.13705E-09
+PKT2    = -1.240924E-15  AT      = -1.132632E+04  LAT     = 6.469047E-03
+WAT     = 6.829220E-04   PAT     = -4.154249E-10  UTE     = -2.309089
+LUTE    = 1.662427E-07   WUTE    = 1.244801E-07   PUTE    = -5.627924E-14
+UA1     = -3.461758E-10  LUA1    = 1.747495E-16   WUA1    = -1.42065E-16
+PUA1    = 7.171442E-23   UB1     = 0              UC1     = -2.38157E-12
+LUC1    = -2.895726E-18  WUC1    = -1.990052E-17  PUC1    = 1.004497E-23
+KT1L    = 0              PRT     = -1E-18         CJ      = cjn
+MJ      = 0.4960069      PB      = 0.9173808      CJSW    = cjswn
+MJSW    = 0.443145       PBSW    = 0.9173808      CJSWG   = cjgaten
+MJSWG   = 0.443145       PBSWG   = 0.9173808      HDIF    = hdifn
+RS      = 0              RD      = 0
+ACM     = 12             LDIF    = 1.2E-07        RSH     = 4.5
+CTA     = 7.707813E-04   CTP     = 5.512283E-04   PTA     = 1.167715E-03
+PTP     = 1.167715E-03   N       = 1              XTI     = 3
+CGDO    = 'cgon'         CGSO    = 'cgon'         CAPMOD  = 0
+NQSMOD  = 0              XPART   = 1              CF      = 0
+TLEV    = 1              TLEVC   = 1              JS      = 1E-06
+JSW     = 5E-11           )

*PMOS DEVICES MODEL

.MODEL pmos PMOS (                               LEVEL   = 49
+VERSION = 3.1            LMIN    = 2.4E-7         LMAX    = '5.0E-7-dxl'
+XL      = '3e-8+dxl'
+XW      = '0+dxw'        TNOM    = 25             TOX     = toxp
+CALCACM = 1              SFVTFLAG= 0              VFBFLAG = 1
+XJ      = 1E-7           NCH     = 4.1589E17
+LLN     = 1              LWN     = 1              WLN     = 1
+WWN     = 1              LINT    = 1.2365E-8      WINT    = 7.8E-9
+MOBMOD  = 1              BINUNIT = 2              DWG     = 0
+DWB     = 0              VTH0    = 'dvthp-0.6236538' LVTH0   = 2.649834E-8
+WVTH0   = 3.214189E-8    PVTH0   = -3.22268E-15   K1      = 0.4198155
+LK1     = 5.770498E-8    WK1     = 5.577151E-8    PK1     = -2.81684E-14
+K2      = 0.0429467      LK2     = -2.296405E-8   WK2     = -1.355302E-8
+PK2     = 6.848271E-15   K3      = 0              DVT0    = 0
+DVT1    = 0              DVT2    = 0              DVT0W   = 0
+DVT1W   = 0              DVT2W   = 0              NLX     = 0
+W0      = 0              K3B     = 0              VSAT    = 1.443912E5
+LVSAT   = -7.688012E-4   WVSAT   = -6.083648E-3   PVSAT   = 2.186471E-10
+UA      = 1.846811E-9    LUA     = -3.27694E-16   WUA     = -2.82106E-16
+PUA     = 7.180233E-23   UB      = -7.84535E-19   LUB     = 4.772849E-25
+WUB     = 2.599205E-25   PUB     = -1.46530E-31   UC      = -1.75560E-10
+LUC     = 3.360832E-17   WUC     = 1.504425E-17   PUC     = -1.30556E-23
+RDSW    = 1.03E3         PRWB    = 0              PRWG    = 0
+WR      = 1              U0      = 0.0136443      LU0     = -7.22084E-10
+WU0     = -1.088554E-9   PU0     = 2.730854E-16   A0      = 0.1071803
+LA0     = 4.64252E-7     WA0     = 5.383179E-7    PA0     = -1.32033E-13
+KETA    = -4.943762E-3   LKETA   = -3.565304E-9   WKETA   = -5.226247E-9
+PKETA   = 2.640665E-15   A1      = 0              A2      = 0.4
+AGS     = 0.1664005      LAGS    = 1.19106E-7     WAGS    = 5.29237E-8
+PAGS    = -2.67304E-14   B0      = 0              B1      = 0
+VOFF    = -0.0592623     LVOFF   = -1.96686E-8    WVOFF   = -1.486398E-8
+PVOFF   = 7.510321E-15   NFACTOR = 0.8588103      LNFACTOR= -1.158881E-7
+WNFACTOR= 1.210664E-8    PNFACTOR= -6.11712E-15   CIT     = 6.439495E-5
+LCIT    = 2.916437E-10   WCIT    = -3.11284E-11   PCIT    = 1.572825E-17
+CDSC    = 0              CDSCB   = 0              CDSCD   = 0
+ETA0    = -3.819468E-3   LETA0   = 2.155422E-9    WETA0   = 8.235612E-10
+PETA0   = -4.16037E-16   ETAB    = 1.334637E-3    LETAB   = -7.93631E-10
+WETAB   = 5.284657E-11   PETAB   = -2.68353E-17   DSUB    = 0
+PCLM    = 0.1098002      LPCLM   = 6.874263E-7    WPCLM   = 6.724724E-7
+PPCLM   = -1.97766E-13   PDIBLC1 = 0              PDIBLC2 = 5.801323E-3
+LPDIBLC2= -1.81964E-9    WPDIBLC2= -5.853396E-9   PPDIBLC2= 2.957545E-15
+PDIBLCB = 0.1921199      DROUT   = 0              PSCBE1  = 7.19E8
+PSCBE2  = 1E-20          PVAG    = 0              DELTA   = 0.01
+ALPHA0  = 0              BETA0   = 30             KT1     = -0.3248987
+LKT1    = -1.160393E-8   WKT1    = 4.153356E-8    PKT1    = -4.62347E-15
+KT2     = -0.0367632     AT      = 1E4            UTE     = -1.04
+UA1     = 3.992421E-10   UB1     = -9.23294E-19   LUB1    = -5.28718E-26
+WUB1    = -6.13069E-26   PUB1    = 1.503674E-32   UC1     = -1.00699E-12
+KT1L    = 0              PRT     = 0              CJ      = cjp
+MJ      = 0.4812153      PB      = 0.9134669      CJSW    = cjswp
+MJSW    = 0.3237595      PBSW    = 0.9134669      CJSWG   = cjgatep
+MJSWG   = 0.3237595      PBSWG   = 0.9134669      HDIF    = hdifp
+LDIF    = 1.2E-7         ACM     = 12             RS      = 0
+RD      = 0              RSH     = 3.5            CTA     = 8.3043E-4
+CTP     = 4.30175E-4     PTA     = 1.3004E-3      PTP     = 1.3004E-3
+CGDO    = cgop           CGSO    = cgop
+CAPMOD  = 0              NQSMOD  = 0              XPART   = 1
+CF      = 0              N       = 1              XTI     = 3
+TLEV    = 1              TLEVC   = 1              JS      = 3E-7
+JSW     = 5E-12           )
*
.ENDL MOS

Comment: It looks like your inspiration comes from [here, p.29](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/ic541ca/ic541ca_f01/Notes/chapter6.pdf). It won't hurt if you include the `berkeley_model.txt` library (link or otherwise).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you! Yes, that is where it is from. I have now put the berkeley_model.txt in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `M1` and `M4` have the D/S reversed: `M4` can't have its drain grounded while the source is above ground, and `M1` needs to propagate the signal from input to output, and that will be from drain to source.

I'm no expert in CMOS, but from what I remember, `0.5u/0.25u` signifies `L/W`, but I have met `W/L`, too. Since I can't find in the linked document what order they are using, I have just used it as `W/L` (`L/W` yields a different transfer).

Your input sources don't seem to be set up as per the testing as described in the document: the black trace is with `B=Vdd` and `A=[0...Vdd]`, while the other two are with either `A=0` or `A=Vdd`, and `B=[0...Vdd]`.

Lastly, the contents of `berkeley_model.txt` is not entirely compatible with LTspice, so I had to prune it a bit: I left the definitions for `NMOS` and `PMOS`, but I only kept the `.params` for the `TT` section (the first); I deleted the rest.

With these changes, the outputs looks somewhat closer to what the picture shows:

[image: test]

For `A` there's a ramp from `0` to `Vdd`, and for `B` a little trick to have both transfers functions as output: if `x==0` then `B=Vdd` else `B=A` (ramp). Note that there's no need to plot `V(out)` as a function of `V(in)` (by replacing `time` on the X-axis with `V(in)`) since the inputs are simple ramps.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help!!! I definitely understand what's going on now with this information. @aconcernedcitizen